# Blocking popupWindow launching within a popupWindow

Tags: android

A user brought a bug to my attention. I'm launching a popupWindow and displaying an edit text field. It appears his device is attempting to launch another popupWindow when he interacts with the EditText field (Probably a spell checker or something similar). Now I've heard of issues with popupWindows having issues launching other popupWindows, but I'm not sure how, or if, I can block this one because the calling function is an HTC library which I can't control.

I can't see the HTC code, but I'm guessing it's trying to invoke the popup using "this" as the context, which in my case is a popupWindow. Then again, I could be way off base with the cause of the problem. Any ideas?

```
0android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRoot$W@479562d0 is not valid; is your activity running?
1at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
2at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
3at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
4at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:828)
5at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:688)
6at com.htc.textselection.SelectionAnchor.show(SelectionAnchor.java:121)
7at com.htc.textselection.TextSelectionMethodImpl.showAnchorCursorMode(TextSelectionMethodImpl.java:1290)
8at com.htc.textselection.TextSelectionMethodImpl.onTouchInEditText(TextSelectionMethodImpl.java:2113)
9at com.htc.textselection.TextSelectionMethodImpl.onTouchEvent(TextSelectionMethodImpl.java:1922)
10at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7166)
11at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3818)
12at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1131)
13at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1131)
14at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1806)
15at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
16at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
17at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5073)
18at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
19at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
20at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
21at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
22at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```